# Error APIRest JBPM 6.2 RemoteRuntimeEngineFactory

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb

The code is:

```
public void showTask() throws Exception{
    URL direccion = new URL("http://"+ip +":"+port+"/business-central");
    RuntimeEngine engine=RemoteRuntimeEngineFactory.newRestBuilder()
            .addUrl(direccion)
            .addDeploymentId(deploymentID)
            .addUserName(usuario)
            .addPassword(pass)
            .build();
    KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();
    TaskService taskService = engine.getTaskService();
    AuditService a=engine.getAuditService();    
    System.out.println(taskService.getTaskById(158).getName());
```

The POM is:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ApiRestJBPM</groupId>
  <artifactId>ApiRestJBPM</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ApiRestJBPM</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jbpm.version>6.2.0.Final-redhat-4</jbpm.version>
      </properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
       <artifactId>kie-remote-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-services-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>rh-repository</id>
      <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

The error is:

```
[main] ERROR org.kie.services.client.api.command.AbstractRemoteCommandObject - Unable to retrieve response content from request with status org.kie.services.client.serialization.jaxb.impl.JaxbRestRequestException cannot be cast to org.kie.services.client.serialization.jaxb.rest.JaxbExceptionResponse: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.kie.services.client.serialization.jaxb.impl.JaxbRestRequestException cannot be cast to org.kie.services.client.serialization.jaxb.rest.JaxbExceptionResponse
org.kie.remote.client.api.exception.RemoteCommunicationException: Unable to retrieve content from response!
    at org.kie.services.client.api.command.AbstractRemoteCommandObject.executeRestCommand(AbstractRemoteCommandObject.java:427)
    at org.kie.services.client.api.command.AbstractRemoteCommandObject.executeCommand(AbstractRemoteCommandObject.java:128)
    at org.kie.services.client.api.command.TaskServiceClientCommandObject.getTaskById(TaskServiceClientCommandObject.java:314)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.kie.services.client.serialization.jaxb.impl.JaxbRestRequestException cannot be cast to org.kie.services.client.serialization.jaxb.rest.JaxbExceptionResponse
    at org.kie.services.client.api.command.AbstractRemoteCommandObject.executeRestCommand(AbstractRemoteCommandObject.java:411)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I formatted the stack trace, but still you need to provide more details on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the **user/pass** wrong error or the role of user for rest is not there - role is **"rest-all"**

Kind regards